# Efficiently gathering data from a game board

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Say I have a connect-4 board, it's a 7x6 board, and I want to store what piece is being stored in what spot on that board. Using a 2-array would be nice, on the fact that I can quickly visualize it as a board, but I worry about the efficiency of looping through an array to gather data so often.

What would be the most efficient way of 1) Storing that game board and 2) Gathering the data from the said game board?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “storing” and “gathering”?

Comment: I guess the best way to put it is 
Storing is the equivalent of putting the data into an array (I.e he has a red piece on (5,7))
Gathering is the equivalent of looping through an array to gather all the data stored inside

Comment: The same syntax `board[4][6]` is used for your definitions of both “storing” and “gathering”. Is that really all you are asking? (I’m voting to close as unclear.)

Answer (score 1):

The trite answer is that at 7x6, it's not going to be a big deal: Unless you're on a microcontroller this might not make a practical difference. However, if you're thinking about this from an [algorithm](/questions/tagged/algorithm) perspective, you can reason about the operations; "storing" and "gathering" are not quite specific enough. You'll need to think through exactly which operations you're trying to support, and how they would scale if you had thousands of columns and millions of pieces. Operations might be:

- Read whether a piece exist, and what color it is, given its `x` and `y` coordinates.
- When you add a piece to a column, it will "fall". Given a column, how far does it fall, or what would the new `y` value be for a piece added to column `x`? At most this will be `height` times whatever the cost of reading is, since you could just scan the column.
- Add a piece at the given `x` and `y` coordinate.
- Scan through all pieces, which is at most `width` times `height` times the cost of reading.

Of course, all of this has to fit on your computer as well, so you care about storage space as well as time.

Let's list out some options:

1. Array, such as `game[x][y]` or `game[n]` where `n` is something like `x * height + y`: Constant time (`O(1)`) to read/write given `x` and `y`, but `O(width * height)` to scan and count, and `O(height)` time to figure out how far a piece drops. Constant space of `O(width * height)`. Perfectly reasonable for 7x6, might be a bad idea if you had a huge grid (e.g. 7 million x 6 million).
2. Array such as `game[n]` where each piece is added to the board and each piece contains its `x` and `y` coordinate: `O(pieces)` time to find/add/delete a piece given `x` and `y`, `O(pieces)` scan time, `O(pieces)` space. Probably good for an extremely sparse grid (e.g. 7 million x 6 million), but needlessly slow for 7x6.
3. HashMap as Grant suggests, where the key is a Point data object you write that contains `x` and `y`. `O(1)` to read/write, `O(height)` to see how far a piece drops, `O(pieces)` time to scan, `O(pieces)` space. Slightly better than an array, because you don't need an empty array slot per blank space on the board. There's a little extra memory per piece entry for the HashMap key object, but you could effectively make an enormous board with very little extra cost, which makes this slightly better than option 1 if you don't mind writing the extra Point class.
4. An array of resizable column arrays, e.g. List. This is similar to an array of fixed arrays, but because List stores its size and can allocate only as much memory as needed, you can store the state very efficiently including how far a piece needs to fall. Constant read/write/add, constant "fall" time, `O(pieces) + O(width)` scan time, `O(pieces) + O(width)` space because you don't need to scan/store the cells you know are empty.

Given those options, I think that an array of Lists (#4) is the most scalable solution, but unless I knew it needed to scale I would probably choose the array of arrays (#1) for ease of writing and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but I think you're looking a hashmap (a form of hashtable) if you want efficiency.

Here's the documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html

HashMap provides expected constant-time performance O(1) for most operations like add(), remove() and contains().

Since you're using a 7x6 board, you can simply name your keys and values A1 ... A6 for example.